# KnockoutJS - Sorting with Isotope

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-isotope

I am trying to display a list of products, and make them sortable by using Isotope. The problem is, the sort function does nothing and returns no errors. Also, overflow:hidden, is being applied to every product except the first one.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tvx07j7c/

JS:

```
  var $container = $('#phoneCatalog-Container').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.phoneCatalog-Item',
      getSortData: {
          price: function ($elem) {
              return $elem.find('.phoneCatalog-Price').text();
          }
      }
  });

  $('.target').on('click', 'button', function () {
      $container.isotope({
          sortBy: price
      });
  });



  function Item(phoneID, phoneMake, phoneModel, phoneAlias, price) {
      this._phoneID = ko.observable(phoneID);
      this.phoneMake = ko.observable(phoneMake);
      this.phoneModel = ko.observable(phoneModel);
      this.phoneAlias = ko.observable(phoneAlias);
      this.price = ko.observable(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 5);

      this.displayName = ko.computed(function () {
          return this.phoneMake() + " " + this.phoneModel();
      }, this);

  }
  // Animation callbacks for the planets list
  this.showPhoneElement = function (elem) {
      if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).hide().fadeIn(700)
  }
  this.hidePhoneElement = function (elem) {
      if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).fadeIn("fast", function () {
          $(elem).remove();
      })
  }


  sortBy = function (field) {
      console.log(field)
      this.filtereditems.sort(function (a, b) {
          return a[field] < b[field] ? -1 : 1;
      });
  };


  var viewModel = {
      items: ko.observableArray([]),
      selectedfilter: ko.observable(""),
      selectedBrand: ko.observable(""),
      selectedIndex: ko.observable(""),
      pageSize: ko.observable(3),
      pageIndex: ko.observable(0)

  };




  viewModel.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
      var filter = this.selectedfilter().toLowerCase();
      if (!filter) {
          var t = this.selectedBrand().toLowerCase();
          if (!t || t == "all") return this.items();
          return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function (item) {
              return item.phoneMake().toLowerCase() == t;
          });
      }

  }, viewModel);

  viewModel.optionSelector = function (selector, data) {
      //option = selector;

      switch (selector) {
          case "brand":
              this.selectedfilter("");
              this.selectedIndex("");
              this.selectedBrand(data);
              break;
          case "index":
              this.selectedfilter("");
              this.selectedBrand("");
              this.selectedIndex(data);
              break;
          default:
              this.selectedfilter("");
              this.selectedIndex("");
              this.selectedBrand("all");
              break;
      }
  };


  var JSONdataFromServer = '[{"phoneID":"54a7a00bc6164c14deed643d","phoneMake":"Samsung","phoneModel":"x200","phoneAlias":"BuggyMorph","price":200},{"phoneID":"54a7a00b8d6650941f5a405f","phoneMake":"Nokia","phoneModel":"M592","phoneAlias":"BuggyMorph","price":300},{"phoneID":"54a7a00b4b93f209cabbdd33","phoneMake":"Motorola","phoneModel":"XT2042","phoneAlias":"BuggyMorph","price":300},{"phoneID":"54a7a00b3dec0d20713f8ca0","phoneMake":"LG","phoneModel":"XT2042","phoneAlias":"BeastlyPhone","price":300},{"phoneID":"54a7a00b69cca65ce8bf50ef","phoneMake":"Motorola","phoneModel":"x100","phoneAlias":"Triton","price":200},{"phoneID":"54a7a00baa7f43c455c07538","phoneMake":"Lenovo","phoneModel":"XT2042","phoneAlias":"BuggyMorph","price":200},{"phoneID":"54a7a00bd6ce0b095fd20ee4","phoneMake":"Motorola","phoneModel":"XT2042","phoneAlias":"BeastlyPhone","price":200},{"phoneID":"54a7a00bdde7b4ebb27d5e2f","phoneMake":"LG","phoneModel":"x200","phoneAlias":"BeastlyPhone","price":300},{"phoneID":"54a7a00b4eb0e09c9b47b64a","phoneMake":"Alcatel","phoneModel":"x100","phoneAlias":"BeastlyPhone","price":100},{"phoneID":"54a7a00bce4e8ea2e3936b55","phoneMake":"Apple","phoneModel":"x200","phoneAlias":"BeastlyPhone","price":200},{"phoneID":"54a7a00be1848cc46c3ee7c9","phoneMake":"Apple","phoneModel":"XT2042","phoneAlias":"BeastlyPhone","price":200},{"phoneID":"54a7a00b87ee74aa7b25e708","phoneMake":"LG","phoneModel":"x100","phoneAlias":"BuggyMorph","price":200},{"phoneID":"54a7a00b1f69852c1ba84ea5","phoneMake":"Samsung","phoneModel":"M592","phoneAlias":"Triton","price":300},{"phoneID":"54a7a00b4677c54e38af8d81","phoneMake":"Apple","phoneModel":"XT2042","phoneAlias":"Triton","price":200},{"phoneID":"54a7a00b0d2524cf57688eda","phoneMake":"Lenovo","phoneModel":"x100","phoneAlias":"BeastlyPhone","price":100}]';

  var dataFromServer = ko.utils.parseJson(JSONdataFromServer);

  //do some basic mapping (without mapping plugin)


  //     $.getJSON("/json/getPhoneCatalog", function (data) {
  //       var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (item) {
  //          return new Item(item._phoneID, item.phoneMake, item.phoneModel, item.phoneAlias, item.price);
  //      });
  //        viewModel.items(mappedData);



  var dataFromServer = ko.utils.parseJson(JSONdataFromServer);

  //do some basic mapping (without mapping plugin)
  var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(dataFromServer, function (item) {
      return new Item(item.phoneID, item.phoneMake, item.phoneModel, item.phoneAlias, item.price);
  });


  viewModel.items(mappedData);
```

HTML:

```
<div class='liveExample'> <span data-bind='text: filteredItems().length'>&nbsp;</span>

    <section> <strong>Filter: </strong>

        <input id="search" data-bind="value: selectedfilter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
    </section>
    <section id="Brand"> <strong>By Brand: </strong>
 <a href="#all" data-bind='click: function() {optionSelector("brand", "all")}'>All</a>
 <a href="#Apple" data-bind='click: function() {optionSelector("brand", "Apple")}'>Apple</a>
 <a href="#Samsung" data-bind='click: function() {optionSelector("brand", "Samsung")}'>Samsung</a>

    </section>
    <button class="target" data-sort-by="price">Sort by price</button>
    <div>
        <div id="phoneCatalog-Container" data-bind="template: {
                               foreach: filteredItems,
                               beforeRemove: hidePhoneElement,
                               afterAdd: showPhoneElement }" class="phoneCatalog-Item"> <span data-bind="text: phoneMake"></span>
 <span data-bind="text: phoneModel"> </span>
 <span data-bind="text:  '$' + price()" class="phoneCatalog-Price"> </span>

            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with isotope but I've had a quick look at their doco and also based on my experience with Knockout and jQuery plugins I can make the following recommendations

1. Your click handler for the sort doesn't fire.  `$('.target').on('click', 'button', fn)` means attach a click event to all button **descendents** of any element with the "target" class. This should be `$('button.target').on('click', fn)`
2. When if does fire, your sortBy argument should be a string 'price'
3. Isotope appears to scan the DOM and catalogue all children of the parent element.  When it initially loads the template bindings hasn't fired yet to there are no children.  You need to force isotope to reload the children whenever the `filteredItem` observableArray is changed **AND** after the initial binding.
   Add `$container.isotope('reloadItems')` immediately after `ko.applyBindings` **AND** as the last statement in the optionSelector function after all observables have been updated.

Doing all 3 then shows another problem with your sample in that Isotope is configured to look for child elements with the "phoneCatalog-Item" class, but that class is on your "phoneCatalog-Container" element, not on any of your child elements repeated.  So it still doesn't find any child elements.

4. You need to add a DIV wrapper around your 2 spans and move the "phoneCatalog-Item" css class

i.e.

```
<div id="phoneCatalog-Container" data-bind="...">
  <div class="phoneCatalog-Item">
    <span>...
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another observation, you are mixing jQuery and Knockout for DOM manipluation.  Whenever knockout rebuilds all the children of container the Isotope plugin will lose track of all (or some) the old child nodes, but when you sort via Isotope it will re-arrange all the element that Knockout created.

Ideally you shouldn't mix the two.

Either move the sort functionality to the filteredItems computed or move the filter functionality to isotope `$container.isotope({ filter: ... })`